# Generating a finite state machine from regular grammar

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-state-machine

Just want to make sure that the way I solved this question is correct since I looked around online and am still not sure about this part:
Question: draw a finite state machine that generates $\{0^∗(10+11)^∗\}$

From what I understood in the powerpoint:

1. step 1 : 1 state per symbol, so $s_0, s_1$
2. step 2 : 1 additional state as finishing state, $s_f$
3. Rules for producting the expresssion:

if $A \rightarrow aB$ there is a transition between $s_A$ and $s_b$

if $A \rightarrow a$, $s_A$ is an accept state

$$S \rightarrow \epsilon$$
$$S \rightarrow AB$$
$$A \rightarrow 0A, \space \epsilon$$

At this point I'm not sure how to write the production rules anymore ... if I understood correctly $(10+11)^∗$ means all combinations of 10, 11, 1011 and 1101 so it can be written as $ 1 (1 \cup 0)$.

Intuitively I understand that $s_0$ is a accept state and loops back on itself, then transitions into $s_1$ which is not an accept state, then transitions into an accept state $s_f$ when either 1 or 0 is read which can then transfer back to $s_1$ when an 1 is read.

Here's an attempt I made:
$$B \rightarrow 1B$$ 
$$B \rightarrow 0B$$ 
$$B \rightarrow 0$$
$$B \rightarrow 1$$

however this would allow for strings such as 1001 which is not allowed. I've also tried

$$B \rightarrow 10B$$
$$B \rightarrow 11B$$
$$B \rightarrow \epsilon$$

But I'm not sure how this translate to a state machine.

Thanks

Comment: $(10+11)^*$ means any number of repetitions of either $10$ or $11$. You could write it as $(1(0+1))^*$

Comment: Anyway, take a look at [Thompson's construction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've just figured it out, gonna post the answer tomorrow

Comment: Are you trying to construct a deterministic or nondeterministic automaton?